# uninitialized constant error when instantiating class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to instantiate a class from a string, but I keep getting an `unitialized constant error Twitter` whenever I call it, though: `<%= share 'twitter', @post %>`

```
@provider = provider.classify.constantize.send(:new, post, link)
```

I tried instantiating the class this way:

```
"SharingHelper::Sharer::#{provider}".classify.constantize.send(:new, post, link)
```

But that caused a `wrong constant name twitter`.

```
module SharingHelper
  def share(provider, post)
    Sharer.new(provider, post).generate
  end

  class Sharer
    def initialize(provider, post)
      @provider = provider.classify.constantize.send(:new, post)
    end

    def generate
      link_to @provider.class.name, @provider.url
    end
  end

  class BaseProvider
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

    def initialize(post)
      @post = post
    end

    def url
      ADDRESS + post_data
    end
  end

  class Facebook < BaseProvider
    ADDRESS  = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&'

    private    
    def post_data
      # do stuff
    end
  end

  class Twitter < BaseProvider
    ADDRESS  = 'https://twitter.com/share?'

    private    
    def post_data
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `"SharingHelper::"` to your provider string before you `:constantize` it.  It looks like you're trying to find a top-level `Twitter` rather than `SharingHelper::Twitter`.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I did try that, but I got a `wrong constant name twitter`: `"SharingHelper::Sharer::#{provider}".classify.constantize.send(:new, post)`

Comment: I also tried with `@provider = "SharingHelper::#{provider}".constantize.send(:new, post)` and got the same error `wrong constant name twitter`

Comment: You need to force it to capitalize Twitter.  Your classify and constantize methods aren't quite smart enough to know to `:titleize` that word.